# Automatically Select First UITableView Textbox

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a tableview that accepts login credentials. I would like to have my app automatically select the first tableview text box upon loading or appearing. I would like the cursor to be placed in the "Email Address" field and for the keyboard to be raised automatically. I can't seem to figure this out. Anyone have any ideas? Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Use this `[emailTextField becomeFirstResponder];`

Comment: I suggest you must have static table view, you can have IBOutlets to textfield and make it the first responder in view did load or view did appear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to assign the first responder to that `UITextView`...

For example:

```
[textField becomeFirstResponder]
```

You can do it in the viewDidAppear of the UIViewController.

Answer (score 2):

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewDidAppear:animated];

NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

myTextField = (UITextField *)[cell viewWithTag:kMyTextFieldTag];
[myTextField becomeFirstResponder];
}
```